# Copying backup files from a network drive daily, need different dated copies for the end of each day

Tags: date, batch-file, time, scripting, backup

I am trying to backup files from a network drive to my C: drive. for the copy I am using:

```
xcopy "\MY_SERVER_IP\SharedDRIVE\TEST*" "C:\Test_Folder" /D /E /C /I /H /Y
```

Is there any way I can have the date added onto this and the information not replace but instead compound and have a daily record of changes made to the files but not lose older copies? This will work for copying the most current information, but I need many months of records not just the most current copy.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a way of getting a DateTime string independent of localization:

```
for /f "tokens=1 delims=." %%i in ('wmic os get localdatetime^|find "."') do set dt=%%i
```

This is format `YYYYMMDDHHMMSScc`

You can shorten this string to your needs. for example:

```
set dt=%dt:~0,8%
```

will set it to `YYYYMMDD` only.

```
set dt=%dt:~0,12%
```

will set it to `YYYYMMDDHHMM`

Then you can copy like this:

```
xcopy "\MY_SERVER_IP\SharedDRIVE\TEST*" "C:\Test_Folder_%dt%" /D /E /C /I /H /Y
```